# How to compare only a portion of two files containing the same column information?

Tags: python, diff

I am trying to compare two model output files but the model simulations have different date ranges so I need to compare the files based on similar simulation dates.  Below is an image of the files I am comparing.  Specifically I need to start the comparison at 2010-1-1 in both files.  I do not want to simply just skip the first lines of the second file because I want to be able to use the comparison method for multiple model runs with different date ranges

[image]

I have compared the files using difflib but have been unable to figure out how to run the comparisons based only on similar date entries.

```
for line in difflib.unified_diff(dif1, dif2):
    print (line)
```

Using the above method I get that all lines are different.

Files can be downloaded here. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tg6y16gix7ran42/AADpMNcZd2ugPQ28Z30Bj9bWa?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
def first_file():

    while True:
        x = int(input('Column: '))
        if x == 0:
            break
        with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                if 'tide' in line or 'Date' in line:
                    pass
                else:
                    a = line.split()
                    compare(a,x)
                        

    
def compare(a,x):
    with open('test1.txt', 'r') as f1:
        for line1 in f1:
            if 'tide' in line1 or 'Date' in line1:
                pass
            else:
                b = line1.split()
                if a[1] == b[1]:
                    if a[x+2] != b[x+2]:
                        print(a[1])
                        print(a[x+2] + ' != ' + b[x+2])
    return

first_file()
```

Comment: Thanks Ktoto.  I implemented the code but I keep getting the following error Column: 2010
IndexError: list index out of range.  Do you have any thoughts?  I thought about converting it to a csv maybe that would help

Comment: Can you post the datasets you're using, your input and your output?

Comment: Comparison files can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tg6y16gix7ran42/AADpMNcZd2ugPQ28Z30Bj9bWa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

`difflib` compares two files line by line. It doesn't care about the meaning of the data, but only compares the text directly. In order to do what you want, you will need to write the code yourself to parse the files and then compare the parts you want to compare. I suggest you start by writing a parser with either the standard `csv` package or with `pandas`. Then you should develop an algorithm to compare the two data structures. Start by describing **in words** the steps to compare them. Then translate those words into code.